# How to compile C++ on Mac OS using TR1

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, tr1

I have a preexisting product that builds on Linux, and I'm trying to port it to Mac OS.

```
msoulier@merlin:~$ xcode-select -v
xcode-select version 2343.
msoulier@merlin:~$ g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

The problem is that it uses the tr1/tuple library, and for some reason,
that is not in the default include path.

```
msoulier@merlin:~$ ls /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/tuple
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr1/tuple
```

So it's there, which should be in the include path based on the
--with-gxx-include-dir option above,

And yet

```
msoulier@merlin:~$ cat hello.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tr1/tuple>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
msoulier@merlin:~$ g++ -o hello hello.cpp
hello.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'tr1/tuple' file not found
#include <tr1/tuple>
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Why doesn't this just work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short answer:** call clang++ with `-stdlib=libstdc++`, and the `tr1` headers will be there.

**Long answer:**
The reason for your error and the 2 sets of C++ includes is that macOS/Xcode has two different C++ standard libraries you can build against: an old GNU `libstdc++`, and the new and modern LLVM `libc++`.

As of macOS 10.12 Sierra, the default is now `libc++` and `libstdc++` is deprecated. `libstdc++` is quite old, v4.2.1, and predates C++11 (hence the `tr1` headers). If you're going to be maintaining this code long-term, it'd be worth the time to make it C++11 compliant (i.e. `#include <tuple>`)

**Update:** Xcode 10 no longer allows building against `libstdc++`. Either update your codebase to use standard C++11 headers, or use Xcode 9 if that's really not an option.

Comment: Where would I find documentation explaining this? I couldn't find anything obvious but I could have missed it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find any Apple documentation explaining the situation. I believe it was mentioned in release notes when libc++ was first included (10.7) and probably when it became the default (10.9?), but that's about it. This `tr1` difference is the biggest incompatibility between the two.

Comment: how to call clag++ with -stdlib=libstdc++? Sorry I am a newbie